# How to insert an n:m-relationship with technical primary keys generated by a sequence?

Tags: database, sequences, data-access

Let's say I have two tables with several fields and in every table there is a primary key which is a technical id generated by a database sequence:

```
table1             table2
-------------      -------------
field11  <pk>      field21  <pk>
field12            field22
```

`field11` and `field21` are generated by sequences.

Also there is a n:m-relationship between `table1` und `table2`, designed in `table3`:

```
table3
-------------
field11  <fk>
field21  <fk>
```

The ids in `table1` und `table2` are generated during the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (table1_seq1.NEXTVAL, ...
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (table2_seq1.NEXTVAL, ...
```

Therefore I don't know the primary key of the added row in the data-access-layer of my program, because the generation of the `pk` happens completely in the database.

What's the best practice to update `table3` now?  How can I gain access to the primary key of the rows I just inserted?

Comment: Altough I solved my problem, I leave this question open for discussing it, since I think it may be a general question.  I have some specifics related to the question I did not mention explicitly, because I wanted to discuss this topic in general.  I am using Ibator Ibatis as DAO framework and this can handle such a case by using the `<generated-key>`-tag in the `<table-name>`-tag in the `ibator.config`-file. For more information on this specific case check out the Ibatis [manual](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/tools/abator/configreference/generatedKey.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you face this problem and you use the Ibator Ibatis framework as DAO-layer (like we do) you can handle this case by using the `<generated-key>`-tag in the ibator.config.

In general you solve this problem by doing a

```
SELECT sequencename.nextval FROM tablename
```

on the table named `tablename` using the sequence `sequencename` to get the next key for the values to insert.

PS: There is no need to pay attention on transactionhandling here, because the next call of the `nextval`-function will return the next sequencevalue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have another (non surrogate) candidate key for these tables? In general it's not very useful to make a surrogate key as the *only* key of any table. Assuming you do have some other key then you can use that to retrieve the rows you insert.